# InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[47,6] = 24 is not in [0, 23)

Tags: tensorflow, indices

I am trying to run the following main.py file and I continuously get the error "InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[138,4] = 23 is not in [0, 23)". I have checked my vocab file. It has exactly 23 words in it.
The code works fine for a single line of new data inserted but when the data is continuous or more then this error pops out. Please help me to rectify this issue.
Below is a small snippet of my code . The line "word_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(variable, word_ids)" is where the error comes.

```
    def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    # For serving features are a bit different
    if isinstance(features, dict):
        features = ((features['words'], features['nwords']),
                    (features['chars'], features['nchars']))

    # Read vocabs and inputs
    (words, nwords), (chars, nchars) = features
    dropout = params['dropout']
    training = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    vocab_words = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(
        params['words'], num_oov_buckets=params['num_oov_buckets'])
    vocab_chars = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(
        params['chars'], num_oov_buckets=params['num_oov_buckets'])
    with Path(params['tags']).open() as f:
        indices = [idx for idx, tag in enumerate(f) if tag.strip() != 'O']
        num_tags = len(indices) + 1
    with Path(params['chars']).open() as f:
        num_chars = sum(1 for _ in f) + params['num_oov_buckets']

    # Char Embeddings
    char_ids = vocab_chars.lookup(chars)
    variable = tf.get_variable(
        'chars_embeddings', [num_chars, params['dim_chars']], tf.float32)
    char_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(variable, char_ids)
    char_embeddings = tf.layers.dropout(char_embeddings, rate=dropout,
                                        training=training)

    # Char LSTM
    dim_words = tf.shape(char_embeddings)[1]
    dim_chars = tf.shape(char_embeddings)[2]
    flat = tf.reshape(char_embeddings, [-1, dim_chars, params['dim_chars']])
    t = tf.transpose(flat, perm=[1, 0, 2])
    lstm_cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(params['char_lstm_size'])
    lstm_cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(params['char_lstm_size'])
    lstm_cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.TimeReversedFusedRNN(lstm_cell_bw)
    _, (_, output_fw) = lstm_cell_fw(t, dtype=tf.float32,
                                     sequence_length=tf.reshape(nchars, [-1]))
    _, (_, output_bw) = lstm_cell_bw(t, dtype=tf.float32,
                                     sequence_length=tf.reshape(nchars, [-1]))
    output = tf.concat([output_fw, output_bw], axis=-1)
    char_embeddings = tf.reshape(output, [-1, dim_words, 50])

    # Word Embeddings
    word_ids = vocab_words.lookup(words)
    glove = np.load(params['glove'])['embeddings']  # np.array
    variable = np.vstack([glove, [[0.] * params['dim']]])
    variable = tf.Variable(variable, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)
    word_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(variable, word_ids)

    # Concatenate Word and Char Embeddings
    embeddings = tf.concat([word_embeddings, char_embeddings], axis=-1)
    embeddings = tf.layers.dropout(embeddings, rate=dropout, training=training)

    # LSTM
    t = tf.transpose(embeddings, perm=[1, 0, 2])  # Need time-major
    lstm_cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(params['lstm_size'])
    lstm_cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell(params['lstm_size'])
    lstm_cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.TimeReversedFusedRNN(lstm_cell_bw)
    output_fw, _ = lstm_cell_fw(t, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=nwords)
    output_bw, _ = lstm_cell_bw(t, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=nwords)
    output = tf.concat([output_fw, output_bw], axis=-1)
    output = tf.transpose(output, perm=[1, 0, 2])
    output = tf.layers.dropout(output, rate=dropout, training=training)

    # CRF
    logits = tf.layers.dense(output, num_tags)
    crf_params = tf.get_variable("crf", [num_tags, num_tags], dtype=tf.float32)
    pred_ids, _ = tf.contrib.crf.crf_decode(logits, crf_params, nwords)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        # Predictions
        reverse_vocab_tags = tf.contrib.lookup.index_to_string_table_from_file(
            params['tags'])
        pred_strings = reverse_vocab_tags.lookup(tf.to_int64(pred_ids))
        predictions = {
            'pred_ids': pred_ids,
            'tags': pred_strings
        }
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)
    else:
        # Loss
        vocab_tags = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file(params['tags'])
        tags = vocab_tags.lookup(labels)
        log_likelihood, _ = tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood(
            logits, tags, nwords, crf_params)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(-log_likelihood)

        # Metrics
        weights = tf.sequence_mask(nwords)
        metrics = {
            'acc': tf.metrics.accuracy(tags, pred_ids, weights),
            'precision': precision(tags, pred_ids, num_tags, indices, weights),
            'recall': recall(tags, pred_ids, num_tags, indices, weights),
            'f1': f1(tags, pred_ids, num_tags, indices, weights),
        }
        for metric_name, op in metrics.items():
            tf.summary.scalar(metric_name, op[1])

        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
                mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)

        elif mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(
                loss, global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
                mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Params
    params = {
        'dim': 300,
        'dim_chars': 100,
        'dropout': 0.5,
        'num_oov_buckets': 1,
        'epochs': 25,
        'batch_size': 20,
        'buffer': 30000000,
        'char_lstm_size': 25,
        'lstm_size': 100,
        'words': str(Path(DATADIR, 'vocab.words.txt')),
        'chars': str(Path(DATADIR, 'vocab.chars.txt')),
        'tags': str(Path(DATADIR, 'vocab.tags.txt')),
        'glove': str(Path(DATADIR, 'glove.npz'))
    }
    with Path('results1/params.json').open('w') as f:
        json.dump(params, f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

    # Word Embeddings
    word_ids = vocab_words.lookup(words)
    glove = np.load(params['glove'])['embeddings']  # np.array
    variable = np.vstack([glove, [[0.] * params['dim']]])
    variable = tf.Variable(variable, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)
    word_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(variable, word_ids)
```

Comment: This is just a wild guess without going over your code, but if there are 23 words in vocab, the highest array index should be 22 (indexed from 0).

Comment: the error is at line 5. I dont understand how do I change the array index. I am new to tensorflow

Comment: @zfabian, do you have any idea how do I solve this?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more of the code. What is your word_ids variable's value before line 5?

Comment: @zfabian, I have added the model's snippet which I am using for your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is not too late for you. 
I have been googling this issue for a while, hopefully got the root of it and turns out it was quite simple. Similar issues unsolved were [here](https://github.com/NLPLearn/R-net/issues/39) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11819).

Chances are: You have seen an example of this embeddings code somewhere and tried to follow it (this was the case for me). However, the case is that coders and tensorflow ***assume*** that the id's for the inputs are sequential. I.e. that if you have 1000 items for example, then your id's are  [0,1,2,3..998,999]. 
However, this is usually not the case with real data where id's are something like ***"xYzVryCmplxNm5m3r"*** (in this case, it will give and error because there are characters in the id and tensorflow will not accept that, it only accepts integers), ***or***, in the very subtle case that is probably your case, the id's are actually integers but not sequential. For example, they can go like : ids=[68632548, 15323, ....].
In this case, tensorflow will accept the input data (because it's integers as expected) and give you this error, because the numbers are not sequential and actually much larger than the number of unique id's (this number+1 is usually set to be the limit for the vocab size).

The solution that worked for me was to map all the id values in the original dataframe to sequential id's, preserving their uniqueness, and then input the same data again (it actually worked !).

The code could be something like:

```
unique_ids=np.unique(old_ids)
sqeuential_ids=[i for i in range(len(unique_ids))]
id_mapping_dict=dict(zip(unique_ids,sqeuential_ids))

def map_ids_to_sequential(original_id):
  return id_mapping_dict[original_id]

df['ids']=df['ids'].apply(map_ids_to_sequential)
```